# Change PHP title on page-to-page basis

Tags: php, html, html-title

So let's say I have multiple pages that are structured like so:

```php
<?
    include_once("head.sub.php");
?>

..HTML continues
```

Logic pertaining to the `<title>` in `head.sub.php`.

```js
if (!isset($g5['title'])) {
    $g5['title'] = $config['cf_title'];
    $g5_head_title = $g5['title'];
}
else {
    $g5_head_title = $g5['title']; // 상태바에 표시될 제목
    $g5_head_title .= " | ".$config['cf_title'];
}
```

This is where it's actually getting the title in `head.sub.php`.

```html
<title><?php echo $g5_head_title; ?></title>
```

Below is what I have attempted to change the HTML `<title>` page-by-page.

```php
<?
    $g5_head_title = 'New Title | example.com';
    include_once("head.sub.php");
?>
```

However, I have not had much success. Currently, it's using the title from `$g5['title']`. I want some pages to keep this default title, while others are custom.

Comment: try `$g5['title'] = 'New Title | example.com';` before your `include_once("head.sub.php");`

Comment: @TKoL No luck with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it an option to change the code block starting with `if (!isset($g5['title'])) {`?? Is that logic editable?

Comment: @TKoL Yes it is.

Comment: You could try adding another `if` block to match the first one, something like `if (isset($customTitle)) $g5['title'] = $customTitle; $g5_head_title = $customTitle;` And then set $customTitle before your `include`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252163/discussion-between-user-and-tkol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the logic to this:

```
if (isset($customTitle)) {
  $g5['title'] = $customTitle;
  $g5_head_title = $customTitle;
} else if (!isset($g5['title'])) {
  $g5['title'] = $config['cf_title'];
  $g5_head_title = $g5['title'];
}
else {
  $g5_head_title = $g5['title']; // 상태바에 표시될 제목
  $g5_head_title .= " | ".$config['cf_title'];
}
```

and then you can have this:

```
<?
    $customTitle = 'New Title | example.com';
    include_once("head.sub.php");
?>
```

Comment: Currently it shows this as the `<title>`: "`New Title | example.com | example.com`" It's loading the other `" | ".$config['cf_title'];`. Whenever I remove the `else` logic it uses the `#customTitle` only. However, that also affects other functionality. Got any other suggestions on logic?

Comment: @user I've made an edit, try that

Comment: This works. So does putting your old `if` logic **following** the previous `if` `else`.